# Tags-based filtering with React Native

Tags: javascript, mysql, react-native, filter, tags

Here's my problem.

When i press 2 buttons, i want the value of this two buttons to become 2 'tags' to use to filter and fetch my data from mysql database using React Native.
Should i use `<Button>` or `<TouchableOpacity>` or `<TouchableHighlight>` or any others to make it work?

How would I implement this? I need a sample code for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All three components (`Button`, `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableHighlight`) can be used for this. They all have `onPress` property that fires a function on user press interaction. Which one to use is mostly your preference of design and implementation.

**Example**

```
_onPress = (value) => {
  console.log(value); // Do something with the value
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => this._onPress('Some Button Value')} title="Press Me!" />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress('Some TouchableOpacity Value')}>
        <Text>{'Press Me!'}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._onPress('Some TouchableHighlight Value')}>
        <Text>{'Press Me!'}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>    
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of those will work, but it's recommended to use `<Pressable>`. Although, Button is a very bad idea because it's too basic and has almost no level of customization.

From react-native docs:

> If you're looking for a more extensive and future-proof way to handle
> touch-based input, check out the Pressable API.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

You can use Pressable like this:

```
<Pressable onPress={onPressFunction}>
<Text>I'm pressable!</Text>
</Pressable>
```